# how to display more than one button in one row in struts 2.0

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts 2.I am designing a page in struts 2.I want to know is how to display more than one button  in one row.I have checked the source code of the page it shows a html table with tr and td tag. When I try to add more buttons on one row they are displayed one below another. Can anybody please tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because S2 uses theme and by default when none provided it use `x_html` as default theme, under this theme while rendering the tag HTML in the browser S2 generate table,tr and td itself.

You have many option either you can use simple theme or css based theme and use your own CSS to handle the display.

Please refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070423/how-to-avoid-generating-more-html-elements-in-struts) for more details

Answer (score 0):

use `theme="simple"`:

```
<s:a theme="simple">test</s:a>
```